# Reference error! Not defined using node.js / Runkit

Tags: node.js, npm, runkit

I'm trying to use this https://npm.runkit.com/globalpayments-api script but I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

When I run the Runkit and add the first code to create a new Credit Card it throws error "ReferenceError: CreditCardData is not defined":

```
const card = new CreditCardData();
card.number = "4111111111111111";
card.expMonth = "12";
card.expYear = "2025";
card.cvn = "123";
```

How I can point CreditCardData to var globalpaymentsApi = require("globalpayments-api") which contains all this consts?

Demo: https://runkit.com/embed/8hidbubpbk8n

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely in your code, function CreditCardData() doesn't exist - this means you didn't import it. Try adding this at the beginning of your .js file:

```js
const { CreditCardData } = require('globalpayments-api');
```

Comment: Hello @filemono. In the case that I have CreditCardData and Address variables would this work? const { CreditCardData, Address } = require('globalpayments-api'); thank you!

Comment: Or I should declare them separately? const { CreditCardData } = require('globalpayments-api'); const { Address } = require('globalpayments-api');

Comment: @JackSpawwor first method is cleaner